# iterating over array with several objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, mocha.js

formatted here well...tried in stack but not working that great... https://gist.github.com/js08/22654f6cd2f160aa2e0a

- i am new to mocha testing..
- right now its working with a single object in an array.
- how to make it work with multiple objects in an array.
- i am not sure how to iterate it
- providing my code below
- single objects in an array:

  ```
  shallowRenderer.render(<SportsList  disclosures ={[ 'id': 'foo', 'text': 'car racing' ]} />);
  ```
- multiple objects in an array:

---

```
shallowRenderer.render(<SportsList  disclosures ={[ {id: 100, text: 'car racing'}, {id: 10, text: 'hello vworld'}, {id: 100, text: 'car racing'} ]} />);

import {expect} from 'chai';
import React from 'react';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import SportsList from '../../src/components/footer/disclosure-list.jsx';
import initializeJsDom from '../test-utils/dom.js';
import {getGridLayoutClasses} from 'sports-css-grids';


describe('shallow renderer tests for disclosure-list ', function() {
    let shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();


    it('should render correctly', () => {

        shallowRenderer.render(<SportsList  disclosures ={[ {id: 100, text: 'car racing'}, {id: 10, text: 'hello vworld'}, {id: 100, text: 'car racing'} ]} />);
        //shallowRenderer.render(<SportsList  disclosures ={[ 'id': 'foo', 'text': 'car racing' ]} />);
        let sportsOutputElement = shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();

        let sportsTitle = sportsOutputElement.props.children[0].key;

        let text = sportsOutputElement.props.children[0].props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML.__html;

       //result succeful for single value 
        expect(sportsTitle).equal('100');
       //result succeful for single value
        expect(text).equal('car racing');
    });



 });

json structure
renderedElement - multiple arrays-- -- > 

{
  "type": "div",
  "key": null,
  "ref": null,
  "props": {
    "className": "pageFooter-disclosures",
    "children": [{
      "type": "p",
      "key": "100",
      "ref": null,
      "props": {
        "dangerouslySetInnerHTML": {
          "__html": "hello world"
        }
      },
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    }, {
      "type": "p",
      "key": "10",
      "ref": null,
      "props": {
        "dangerouslySetInnerHTML": {
          "__html": "hello vworld"
        }
      },
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    }, {
      "type": "p",
      "key": "100",
      "ref": null,
      "props": {
        "dangerouslySetInnerHTML": {
          "__html": "hello world"
        }
      },
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    }]
  },
  "_owner": null,
  "_store": {}
}√
should render correctly(3 ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `expect` from `chai` you can use eql which will test objects for deep equality

```
expect(sportsOutputElement.props.children).to.eql([ {id: 100, text: 'car racing'}, {id: 10, text: 'hello vworld'}, {id: 100, text: 'car racing'} ]);
```

Comment: thanks for your message...can you update in my code...its confusing

Comment: replace the four lines in your code starting with ``//result successfull for single value`` with the line above

Comment: thanks for your reply....but I am getting an error  AssertionError: expected [ Array(3) ] to deeply equal [ Array(3) ]
      + expected - actual

Comment: It seems that the array could come out of order. If that's the case use ``deep.include.members`` instead of ``eqls`` like this ``expect(sportsOutputElement.props.children).to.deep.include.members([ {id: 100, text: 'car racing'}, {id: 10, text: 'hello vworld'}, {id: 100, text: 'car racing'} ]);``

Comment: still I am getting another error  AssertionError: expected [ Array(3) ] to be a superset of [ Array(3) ]

Comment: Do a console.log on the actual array to make sure it's what you expect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106545/discussion-between-texi-rv-and-gabesoft).